# R shiny - updating CheckboxGroupInput based on another CheckboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I want to include the variables of 'Fixed Variables' in 'Random Variables' only when user uncheck the variables in Fixed Variables. Here's the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W1fZ.jpg. There is no error message, just that whenever I try to uncheck any of the variables, it doesn't let me to it. 
Can anyone please help me with this?

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,clientData, session) {
   observe({

     data<-reactive({
        file1<-input$file
        if(is.null(file1)){return()}
        read.table(file=file1$datapath,    sep=input$sep,header=input$header,stringsAsFactors=input$stringsAsFactors)
                  })

        colnames<-names(data())
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Fixed", choices = colnames, selected=colnames) 

        inputVar<-reactive({
              Fixedvar<-input$Fixed
              if(is.null(Fixedvar)){return()}
              subset<-data()[,!(colnames %in% Fixedvar)]
               col<-names(subset)
                col
                             })

       updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Random", choices = inputVar())
               })})



shinyUI(fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel( 

       fileInput("file","Please upload your file"),
       checkboxInput(inputId='header', label='header', value=TRUE),
       checkboxInput(inputId="stringsAsFactors", label="stringsAsFactors", value=FALSE),
        radioButtons(inputId='sep',label='Separator', choices=c(Comma=',',  Semicolon=';',Tab='\t',Space=''), selected=','),
        fluidRow(column(6, wellPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("Fixed", 
                       label = "Fixed Variables","") 
           )),

        column(6, wellPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("Random", label = "Random Variables","") 
         ) ))),


             mainPanel()
            )))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're only using the one `observe`. It runs whenever any reactive element inside it changes - in your case that's anything at all. Specifically, when you change the `"Fixed"` checkbox group, this part of the observe also runs again:

```
colnames<-names(data())
updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Fixed", choices = colnames, selected=colnames)
```

Since your data hasn't changed, it always just sets your choices and selected options to `colnames`. To get around it you need to make your server more modular, with separate observers and reactive elements. Here's a layout that works for your **server.R**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({

    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){ return(mtcars) } # Default data for testing

    read.table(file = file1$datapath, sep = input$sep, header = input$header,
               stringsAsFactors = input$stringsAsFactors)

  })

  colnames <- reactive({ names(data()) })

  observeEvent(data(), {

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Fixed",
      choices = colnames(), selected = colnames()) 

  })

  inputVar <- reactive({

    Fixedvar <- input$Fixed

    if (setequal(colnames(), Fixedvar)) {
      # If sets are equal, return an empty string
      return("")
    } else {
      # Return elements that are only in colnames
      setdiff(colnames(), Fixedvar)
    }

  })

  observeEvent(inputVar(), {

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Random", choices = inputVar())

  })

})
```

I also changed the `inputVar` slightly. When none of the boxes are selected in a `checkboxGroupInput`, it returns `NULL`. So when `input$Fixed` is `NULL`, you actually want to update the options in `"Random"` to *all* of the columns.

There's still a problem though: whenever you check or uncheck a box in the first input, the second one gets updated. This means it's selections also get updated - to everything unchecked. It's a bit of a different problem though; I think you might be able to get around it using `reactiveValues` to store previous values of `"Random"` and using those as the initial values when you update the input choices.

Answer (score 0):

You may need observers. Whenever you want to evaluate reactive expressions, but do not need to return values, you have to use observers. Some observer-like examples are the `renderXXX` functions. More information [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html#observers).

Try this

```
observe({
    colnames<-names(data())
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Fixed", choices = colnames, selected=colnames)
})

# ...

observe({
    iv <- inputVar()
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Random", choices = iv)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have used observer in my code. I tried it with your code too, but I am getting an error message, - 'match' requires vector arguments'.